# background-size: cover w/ Angular2

Tags: css, angular

### Hi everyone,

I'm actually learning *Angular2* and i'm stuck with a ...css issue o_O
I was searching for a similar issue without any success, here we go:

I have a single `main` tag element within the `body`

I set up `background-image` within the `main` div and used `background-size: cover` to fit but it doesn't seems to work at all, the picture doesn't fit to the div..

I'm very confused because it's the first time that it happened to me

*For your information:* I used styleUrls to inject css rules within the component

Code

```
body {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

main {

    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 30px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background: url(../assets/fond.jpg) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 30px 3px 36px -15px grey, -30px 3px 36px -15px grey;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: it has nothing to do with Angular2. check whether your css is getting applied or not !

Comment: I added 'Angular2' because I built the old version w/ React and I've never had this problem and the code worked

Comment: You were almost right, I had to use `-webkit-background-size: cover` I only have to do this w/ Angular o_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<main [style.backgroundSize]="'cover'"></main>
```

Please note the single quotes in between the double quotes. Without them, `cover` would be evaluated as a `$scope` property (which does not exist). You need to pass the value as string.

Alternatively, if you want to control and dynamically change the contents of a `style` directive property, you could just use

```
<main [style.attributeName]="styleHanlder"></main>
```

Where `attributeName` is any DOM element `style` property and `styleHanlder` is the name of your handler function in `$scope`, where you assign values to that property according to your apps' logic. Of course, you can pass a bunch of attributes by using `<main [style]="styleHanlder"></main>`, in which case you'd need to return an object `{attributeName:"value", anotherAttribute:"value"}`.

Comment: Strange. Clean console? Is it loading properly? Make sure your setup works by calling a `$scope` function in your property and `console.log` it.

Comment: Is `<main>` contained in your `ngApp` element? Are you sure you modifiy the right file? Does any other change apply? Do you have cache-ing enabled?

Comment: Yes, clean console. I solved the problem using `-webkit-background-size: cover`... Weird thing, I only need this w/ Angular o_O

Comment: That has nothing to do with Angular. You were testing in Safari. You are supposed to prefix for Safari. It doesn't respect web standards. If you develop for Safari you might discover your app doesn't work for 95% of your users. Always develop in the most popular browser+device combination

Comment: I never used Safari for development, I'm using Chrome

Comment: Chrome does not need `-webkit-background-size` to apply `background-size`. From what you are describing, some*thing* else (a function?) is setting an invalid value to `background-size`. (Or it's unsetting it). Because you are setting a valid value in `-webkit-background-size`, the browser uses it. But this means non`-webkit` browsers will be stuck with the invalid/unset value. Try and find out what's going on. You should be able to inspect it.